# C# assembly loading and resource.dll(s)

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, .net-5

We created a service that allows us to load plugins at startup.

What we do is scan the output directory for dll(s) with a specfic name pattern and call

```
Type pluginInterface = typeof(IPlugin);    
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("My.Plugin.dll");
TypeInfo pluginType = curAssembly.DefinedTypes.Where(t => t.IsAssignableTo(pluginInterface).First();
Activator.CreateInstance(pluginType.AsType());
```

The plugin it self defines it's dependencies and once loaded it registers at the loading environment. It seems to work fine ...

The issue we are facing seems to be a problem with `*.resources.dll`(s)

When we start the application we get a lot of exceptions that `*.resources.dll` could not be found (the dll itself).

So far this happens with

- System.Private.ServiceModel.resources.dll
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.resources.dll
- Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.resources.dll
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.resources.dll

All those libraries were defined as nuget package (either in the plug in or in one of the dependencies).

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.12" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Private.ServiceModel" Version="4.9.1" />
```

The build output shows that e.g. System.Private.ServiceModel.resources.dll is in the language specific subdirectory (`\bin\Debug\net5.0\en`) but the exception states it is looking directly in the ouput directory (e.g. `\bin\Debug\net5.0`)

The other mentioned resources.dlls are not added to the output directory at all.

The exception message:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'C:\MyProject\bin\Debug\net5.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.resources.dll'. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
```

aka System can not find the file ....

Does anyone have ideas what could be wrong and how to fix it?
(Besides finding the resource.dlls and add them manually on every build.)

The current workaround is to reference all the packages in the plugin loader directly. But we do not want to limit e.g. the Entity Framework versions on that way ...

Comment: By design.  Debug > Windows > Exception Settings, tick the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" checkbox until it is a square again.

Answer (score 0):

I had came across with similar problem. My suggestion is to add AssemblyResolved callback function.

When you load the .dll file, your application actually need to load all dependencies. For the missing dependencies, you can write a code to find them in specific places. In code block you can manually load unresolved .dlls.

```
 AppDomain myDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(domainName, null, domaininfo);
 myDomain.SetData("AssemblyName", dllPath);
 myDomain.DoCallBack(() => {
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (s, e) =>
  {
      Assembly assemblyResolved = Assembly.LoadFrom("__DLL_FOLDER__\\" + e.Name.Substring(0, e.Name.IndexOf(",")) + ".dll");
      
      return assemblyResolved;
  };

  Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom((string)AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("AssemblyName"));
```

The other thing came to my mind is that, your application probably want to load .dlls from GAC. Check GAC for missing .dlls